# How to overcome the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column DateList: varchar(4000). There is a list of dates as strings written in Russian. It looks as following:

```
2014-09-26 19:00 2014-09-27 19:00 2014-09-28 19:00 2014-09-29 19:00 2014-09-30 19:00
```

I also have stored procedure that reads DateList and should do something with it. But, the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" comes up. When I update DateList column with the same dates written in English, everything works fine. But, these dates were usually entered in Russian.

I'm not sure if I have to use "nvarchar" instead of "varchar" in the table or there is another way to overcome this issue?

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [FilterDates] (@sString NVARCHAR(4000), @MINDate DATETIME, @MaxDate DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SplitChar NCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @Count INT
    DECLARE @DateLength INT 
    DECLARE @XMLString XML

    SET @SplitChar = ','
    SET @Count = 1      
    SET @DateLength = 17
    SET @sString = RTRIM(@sString) + ' '

   WHILE @Count <= Len(@sString) / 17 - 1
    BEGIN
       SET @sString = STUFF(@sString, @DateLength, 0, ',')

       SET @DateLength = 17 + @DateLength + 1
       SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END

   --Use XML to extract the Date.
   SET @XMLString = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@sString, @SplitChar, '</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

   CREATE TABLE #Temp (DateVal NVARCHAR(4000))

   INSERT INTO #Temp (DateVal)
 SELECT DateValue 
 FROM (SELECT T.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS DateValue FROM @XMLString.nodes('/root/s') T(c)) AS Temp  
 WHERE DateValue BETWEEN @MINDate AND @MaxDate

 SELECT LTRIM((SELECT DateVal AS DateVal FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) AS ExpectedResult
END
```

Here's how I call the stored procedure:

```
declare @sString NVARCHAR(4000)
declare @MINDate DATETIME
declare @MaxDate DATETIME
SELECT @sString = DateList from T_Action where ID = 46591
SET @MINDate = '2014-09-27'
SET @MaxDate = '2014-09-30'
EXEC FilterDates @sString, @MINDate, @MaxDate
```

Comment: Why do you store multiple datetimes in a single varchar field at all? Use a table where each date is a record and link it to the main table via foreign key. And [make that column a `datetime`-column](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Comment: It's some old design and it can't be changed at this moment. I need to solve the issue I mentioned above.

Comment: How are you converting the dates?

Comment: Have you set the language to Russian before running it? - `SET LANGUAGE RUSSIAN;` - *n.b. Could not agree more with Tim, going through the effort of normalising this once is significantly better than messing around with conversions, string splitting etc every time you need to use the list of dates.*

Comment: @GarethD: I entirely agree with you, but the design can't be changed now.

Comment: @kalthir: Please, take a look at the stored procedure I use in the original post.

Comment: Can you post a list of Russian dates that is failing please. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I've already posted it in the original post. They look the same as in English, but the stored procedure fails. I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @Tanner - Comma has been stuffed between every 17 characters check the while loop

Comment: Once again - when I manually updated the value of DateList with the same dates written in English everything works fine. But, of course, I can't do that with all records in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach your splitting method differently for a start, I would use a set of numbers to do this rather than creating a delimited list, then splitting that. A simple example would be:

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(1000) = '2014-09-26 19:00 2014-09-27 19:00 2014-09-28 19:00';
SELECT  Date = SUBSTRING(@s, ((n - 1) * 17) + 1, 17)
FROM    (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS t (n)
WHERE   n <= (LEN(@s) + 1) / 17.0
```

Then expanding this to allow for more than 3 values (up to 1,000) I have just used a stacked CTE to generate a list of 1 - 1000:

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(1000) = '2014-09-26 19:00 2014-09-27 19:00 2014-09-28 19:00';
WITH N1 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS t (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N2.N) FROM N2 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N3)
SELECT  Date = SUBSTRING(@s, ((n - 1) * 17) + 1, 17)
FROM    N3
WHERE   n <= (LEN(@s) + 1) / 17.0;
```

Your problem then arises because the default for Russian is `DMY`, so it is trying to convert `2014-09-26` to the 9th day of the 26th month, e.g. this will throw an error:

```
SET LANGUAGE RUSSIAN;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-26 19:00' AS DATETIME);
```

> Параметры языка изменены на "русский".
>
> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>
> Преобразование типа данных varchar в тип данных datetime привело к выходу значения за пределы диапазона.

Whereas this works:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-26 19:00' AS DATETIME);
```

Because US english is expecing the date in the format `MDY`.

If your dates will always be in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi` then you can use an explicit style when converting to a date:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-09-26 19:00', 120);
```

Then whatever your language settings the conversion will work. e.g.

```
SET LANGUAGE RUSSIAN;
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-09-26 19:00', 120);
GO
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-09-26 19:00', 120);
```

So your final query will be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [FilterDates] (@sString NVARCHAR(4000), @MINDate DATETIME, @MaxDate DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH N1 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS t (N)),
    N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
    N3 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N2.N) FROM N2 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N3)

    SELECT ExpectedResult = 
            LTRIM(( SELECT  ' ' + SUBSTRING(@sString, ((n - 1) * 17) + 1, 17)
                    FROM    N3
                    WHERE   n <= (LEN(@sString) + 1) / 17.0
                    AND     CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@sString, ((n - 1) * 17) + 1, 17), 120) >= @MinDate
                    AND     CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@sString, ((n - 1) * 17) + 1, 17), 120) <= @MaxDate
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'));
END
```

---

**Working example with sample provided in question**

```
DECLARE @Sstring VARCHAR(1000) = '2014-09-26 19:00 2014-09-27 19:00 2014-09-28 19:00 2014-09-29 19:00 2014-09-30 19:00',
        @MinDate DATETIME = '20140927',
        @MaxDate DATETIME = '20141001';
WITH N1 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS t (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N2.N) FROM N2 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N3)

SELECT ExpectedResult = 
        LTRIM(( SELECT  ' ' + SUBSTRING(@sString, ((n - 1) * 17) + 1, 17)
                FROM    N3
                WHERE   n <= (LEN(@sString) + 1) / 17.0
                AND     CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@sString, ((n - 1) * 17) + 1, 17), 120) >= @MinDate
                AND     CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@sString, ((n - 1) * 17) + 1, 17), 120) <= @MaxDate
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'));
```

If you are saying you have a mix of dates in your table, e.g. both `2014-09-26` and `2014-26-09`, then you have very little choice but to sort this out manually, and while you are at it find the person who decided that the best way to store a list of dates was a space delimited string, and punch him square in the teeth. For cases like 26th september (`2014-09-26` or `2014-26-09`) it is easy because you know that if `DMY` conversion fails, you can try `MDY`, it is dates like `2014-11-10` that cause the real issue, if you have not validated the input, then you have no way of knowing whether this is the 10th November, or 11th October. This is worse than a conversion error.

Comment: @tesicg It works as expected for the data provided in the question. If this is not the data you are having a problem with, then it might be helpful to post that.

Comment: The issue stays the same. When I use the hard coded string with the list of dates as you did, it works fine. But, when I use real data from database, the error comes up.

Comment: Then in the database you have invalid dates, or dates stored in a non standard format. There is not much you can do about this. As explained in the answer, if you don't have a fixed format (`yyyy-MM-dd` for example, or `yyyy-dd-MM`) then dates become ambiguous. Since the design is not yours, and you are unable to change it I would approach someone who is able to change it, or did design it and tell them they have a lot of dates to manually sort out and format properly.